# Understanding how to change Javascript properties

Tags: javascript, properties

I have Javascript code on a webpage... I have 2 different help icons.  When clicking on either help icon, I call a routine which builds a modal help popup, but pass different values to the popup so the popup know which help text to display. For simplicity, the two help icons pass values of either 'LEFT' or 'RIGHT'. When I call my routine...

```
openHelpDialog('LEFT');
```

it works, I get the help popup with help based on LEFT.  If I close my browser, and I call the routine

```
openHelpDialog('RIGHT');
```

that works, I get the help popup with help based on the right region of my page.  What does NOT work is if I call one then later call the other from within the same browser window. It APPEARS that the 2nd call (and all thereafter subsequent calls) are not 'updating' the properties to give me the new window.  In short, the 3 variables are not changing, and I don't know why.  Here is my relevant code.

```
function openHelpDialog(whichDiv) {
var helpTitle = '';
var helpSubTitle = '';
var helpContent = '';    

console.log(whichDiv);
if (whichDiv == 'LEFT') {
 helpTitle = 'Path Management Help';
 helpSubTitle = 'Available Opportunities';
 helpContent = '';   
  } else
  {
   helpTitle = 'Path Management Help';
   helpSubTitle = 'Selected Opportunities';
   helpContent = '';      
  };  

$("#iziModalHelp").iziModal({
    title: helpTitle,
    subtitle: helpSubTitle,
   ....
  });

    // Now open the window
   $('#iziModalHelp').iziModal('open');
};
```

What do I need to do to correct this behavior?
Thanks

Comment: You need to edit the `iziModal` function

Comment: @@Quentin - I am... at least I think I am...  I am setting the values of title and subtitle based on what I want them to be, based on whether this is a LEFT or RIGHT help popup.  Unfortunately, this only works the first time I call the routine.  I am doing something wrong, which is why I am posting here...

Comment: Do not confuse "[the function](https://github.com/dolce/iziModal/blob/master/js/iziModal.js)" with "the arguments you pass to the function"